# Changing bad coordinates of GeoJSON shape to coordinates of another GeoJSON shape?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, json

I have two GeoJSON file one with true coordinates, one with wrong coordinates with labels. They both refer to the same geographical object: districts in Georgia. I would like to convert the coordinates of the second one to the coordinates of the first one so I can plot the labels on a web-based mapping tool.

I plotted them on QGis. The good GeoJSON file is the green one. As one can see on the bottom right-hand corner the coordinates are crazy.

[image: ![enter image description here]

How to make the coordinates of the red shape to match the coordinates of the green? 
Is there a tool on QGis to change the coordinates of a shape to match the one of another?

Both files are available [here](https://gofile.io/?c=vSqokI) if you have any other ideas.

Here is an excerpt of the file with the wrong coordinates (red):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              4854546.154083,
              5284008.666675
            ],
            [
              4855951.745246,
              5283252.476637
            ],
            ...
            [
              4854546.154083,
              5284008.666675
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": 69898,
        "parent_id": null,
        "common_id": "Georgia",
        "common_name": "Georgia",
        "has_children": true,
        "shape_type_id": 1,
        "shape_type_name": "Country",
        "value": "No Data",
        "color": null,
        "title_location": "Country: Georgia"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

One can see the crazy longitudes and latitudes.

Here is an excerpt of the file with the good coordinates :

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "georgia",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "GID_0": "GEO",
        "NAME_0": "Georgia"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                41.73014069,
                42.07485962
              ],
              [
                41.73014069,
                42.07458496
              ],
              ...
              [
                45.78749466,
                41.23017502
              ],
              [
                45.7786026,
                41.23553848
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is there only one feature in each layer?

Comment: @csk Yes, they don't look exactly the same though. I'm going to add the first lines.

Comment: I haven't checked your data, but very likely the issue is either *On-the-fly reprojection* is disabled in QGIS, or (even more likely) one of your data sources has a wrong CRS set (set != transformed). the numbers shown are planar coordinates (in *meter* or *feet* or similar).

Comment: @ThingumaBob yes, I do believe it is the second option for the red one. However both layers are dealing with the same objects and the gree one has normal coordinates, so I was wondering if it were possible to change the ones of the first.

Comment: Your "wrong coordinates" look like Pseudo-Mercator (EPSG 3857). Try assigning that coordinate system and see if it lines up.